# Error al configurar Crashlytics en Xcode

Tags: firebase, swift, crahslytics

Estoy intentando agregar `Crashlytics` a mi proyecto pero tengo ujn problema/error ya que no me aparecen los errores en en la consola de `Firebase`

Este es mi `pofile`

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
use_frameworks!
swift_version = "4.0"

target "BProject Name" do

    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
    pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.7.2'
    pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.9.3'
end
```

Este es mi código para el error:

```
@IBAction func volver(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    Crashlytics.sharedInstance().crash()
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    //FIREBASE
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    Fabric.sharedSDK().debug = true
    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    return true
}
```

He seguido las instrucciones de la [Documentación de Google](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?authuser=1) pero no me funciona. No me aparecen los errores en la consola de `Firebase`.

¿Alguna posible solución?

Comment: ¿Ya vinculaste tu App a `Fabric` desde la consola de `Firebase`?  ¿Revisaste [si los errores aparecen en `Fabric` directamente](https://get.fabric.io/?locale=es-ec)?

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano , tengo configurado el proyecto en firebase, pero en fabric no he realizado nada, en las instrucciones de google no decia nada al respecto

Comment: No sé si para iOS sea diferente. Yo tengo una App Android y si intento ver `Crashlytics` desde la consola de `Firebase` me dice que vincule el módulo de errores con `Fabric`. De hecho, ya no reviso los errores desde `Firebase`, sino desde la página misma de `Fabric`. Ellos están migrando todo a `Fabric`, lo cual es una revolución en el seguimiento de errores... es impresionante la cantidad de cosas que tienen y los tipos de seguimiento que puedes configurar desde tu App. [Puedes revisar la doc aquí](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/fabric/overview.html)