# Cierre repentino de la app, si esta con xcode no se cierra. Sucede al cambiar el tipo de teclado desde iphone

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4

He desarrollado un app para `IOS` con `swift`, hasta aqui todo correcto, hice pruebas de debug con xcode y ningún problema. Pero un usuario de la app se ha puesto en contacto conmigo porque cuando va a una pantalla que es un formulario, y hace **click en un campo texto**, se le **cierra la app**.

Conecte su movil al `xcode`, volví a instalar la app y con el movil conectado a `xcode` no tuve ningún problema, pero cuando lo desconecté volvió a pasar lo mismo.

La consola no me daba ningún error. He intentado configurar `Crashlytics`  ([pero no lo he conseguido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/151494/64554)) para ver si consegui detectar el error.

Os pondría el código de la app, pero estoy tan perdido que no se a que puede deberse ya que yo he realizado todas las pruebas en un `Iphone 5s` y todo correcto, el del usuario en concreto es un `Iphone 6 Plus`

**EDITADO**

He dado con el fallo. Sucede al cambiar al teclado de emoticono. Lo he solucionado asi:

```
campo.keyboardType = .asciiCapable
```

¿Como puedo hacer para que si acepte este teclado?

Comment: seguro que no tienes ninguna variable con un maravilloso nil por ahi en medio? Si vas con debug, sabes en que linea crashea?

Comment: No, no tengo ningun nil. Con ekl xcode conectao me funciona bien, sin errores. En algnos iphone funciona bien también, pero en otros no funciona. @Spidvmp

Comment: Puedes validar las versiones de iOS de los teléfonos en lo que estás probando ? , ese puede ser el problema.

Comment: Todos tienen la misma versión: `11.2.6` @mariovzc

Comment: Y es necesario los emoticones en el formulario ??

Answer (score 0):

Y es necesario los emoticones en el formulario ??
ya cambiaste bien la configuración desde el xcode en los atributos del campo ?

ContentType por ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]